# Rails API - JSON includes multiple items and levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

So i'm creating an API. I want to return my questionnaire in JSON.

My questionnaire:

- has many questions through questionnaire_items
- has many contents through questionnaire_items

I also have question_inputs, which belong to a question.

My API needs to return the questionnaire which needs to include:

- Questions - which include question_inputs
- Contents

Using the below code i'm able to include questions, or contents, but not both.

So my questions are:

1. How can I include both questions and contents?
2. How can I include question_inputs with questions?

   def show

   ```
       @questionnaires = Questionnaire.find(params[:id])
       # @questions = @section.questions
       respond_to do |format|
         #format.json  { render :json => @questionnaires.to_json(:include => [:questions]), :callback => params['callback']}
         format.json  { render :json => @questionnaires.to_json(:include => [questionnaire_items: {include: :question,},], ), :callback => params['callback']}
       end
   end
   ```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [active model serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)  is really good for this kind of task

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is either jbuilder (default gem that comes with rails) or active model serializer.

With jbuilder, you create for instance a show.json.jbuilder view and you structure your api response similar to how you would an html response with ERB. for example:

```
json.questionaires do 
  json.name @questionaire.name
  json.array! @questionaire.questions do |question|
    json.name question.name
  end
end
```

You can read more in the docs on jbuilder: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: It's taken me a while to get back to this project, but this is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.

Comment: Although i'm now having trouble with getting it to output as jsonp on a AJAX call. I've tried jpbuilder but it hasn't worked. Have you had any experience of this?

Comment: can't say i have, no